# Why does Docker fail with VSCode running

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, port

My docker service (epst) fails to start if I'm also running VSCode. The error is:

```
ERROR: for epst  Cannot start service epst: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint epst (long-hash): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5123 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

If I shut down VSCode and re-launch docker-compose, then everything comes up fine.

So my question is how do I identify what is binding to port 5123 in VSCode?

Comment: Depends on your OS, in linux it would be ``netstat -tulpn | grep 5123``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might be looking for `lsof -i :5123`?
See [man page for lsof](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof).

This would the return a list of processes running on the port you entered (`5123`).

`COMMAND   PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME`
`appName  5123   yourUser   --   ----             -------------------------`

You could then `kill 5123` to free up the desired port.

Comment: Thanks for the lsof command. I know I can always shut down VSCode while Docker is starting, I'm wondering why Code is grabbing the port.
lsof shows me that Code is under COMMAND

Code\x20H
Question is why?

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since my question was answered - per se.

Comment: @dfdumaresq Have you tried checking if you have more than one terminal instance running in VS Code?
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_managing-multiple-terminals